# Trying to add external Jars to a Java Project (without Maven)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I am trying to add external jars to my Java (without Maven) Project.
But I don't get it to work at all.
The official documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project
says there are 2 ways to do it:
1."You can use the Java Dependency Viewer to add any JAR file to your project."
https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/java/java-project/manage-dependencies.gif
As you can seee in the gif, the dev opens a "referenced libraries" folder.
This folder DOES NOT EXIST for me.
or 2."The other easy way to bring additional JAR files as dependencies is to create a lib/ folder in the root directory of the standalone files and place your JAR files there. Source for foo.jar is automatically detected if there is a foo-sources.jar in the lib/ folder."
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project/lib.mp4

I have the Jar file in the lib\ folder but it still shows me he same error messages.
Are there any steps I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

As it says, place the external jar files in the `...\JAVArpg\lib` folder.

So copy them from wherever you have them now. `cp ../lib/*.jar lib/` is just an *example*.

You can use the Windows Explorer. You don't have to copy the files using a command-line.

Comment: Thanks, now we have sorted this one out. I already copied the JAR in the lib folder before creating the question here, so this is not the deciding error.

Comment: @riggedCoinflip If you had already copied them, why did you try running the `cp` commands?

Comment: @riggedCoinflip Don't know about Visual Studio Code, but in Eclipse you have to do a Refresh of the project for it to see changes to files done outside Eclipse. Can you see the `lib` folder and the `.jar` files from inside VS Code? Are there any interesting options on the right-click context menu of those files, e.g. "add to classpath"?

Comment: The file shows up in VS Code, it only has standard right-click options. The error message I get when trying to `import com.fasterxml.jackson;` (the lib) is `"The import com.fasterxml cannot be resolved"`

Comment: `import com.fasterxml.jackson;` is incomplete. You either import a specific type using `import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;` or you import all types in a package using `import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211006/discussion-between-riggedcoinflip-and-andreas).